# TIMED_WAITING thread marked as runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread dump, in which there is :

```
"http-9443-67" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d5c37e800 nid=0x10331 runnable [0x00007f1d50da9000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x000000032e818150> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:470)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:633)
at ...
```

and

```
"http-9443-69" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d5c8a1000 nid=0x10333 waiting on condition [0x00007f1d511af000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x0000000326940d48> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:470)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:633)
at ...
```

which are **both** in TIMED_WAITING state.

However :

- http-9443-67 is marked as **runnable**
- http-9443-69 is marked as **waiting on condition**

Do you know what it means ?

Comment: I seem to remember that there was a small race condition in the hotspot code which could cause the wrong thread state to be displayed, but I can't find any trace of it. If my memory isn't playing tricks on me, it would certainly explain what you are seeing. Do you have a reproducible test case? Does it depend on JDK version?

Answer (score -1):

The thread halt execution due to invocation of `wait()` and it will resume when 'notify()' is called

Comment: The question is, "Why is one of the threads marked as runnable when its state is TIMED_WAITING?"